# can't submit sitemap to Google webmaster tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I’m having trouble submitting a sitemap to Google webmaster tools. This is something I have done many times and have never had any problems before. I get this error: 
**Description:** 
We encountered an error while trying to access your Sitemap. Please ensure your Sitemap follows our guidelines and can be accessed at the location you provided and then resubmit.
**Example:**
 URL restricted by robots.txt
Truly the robots text is correct,  and so is the sitemap.
Here is the code on the robots.txt
User-agent: * 
Disallow:

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, these may be your problem:

- Your sitemap is not created as Google wants. Try another tool.
- Be sure that you've uploaded your sitemap to a public directory
- Check your sitemap by typing to browser yoursite.com/sitemap.xml
- Check your sitemap file's permissions (7-5-5 was working if I'm not
  wrong)

You can allow indexing everything by robots.txt Try this code (another version of yours):

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to submit your sitemap xml to Google with command line. Using curl command: curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://google.com/ping?sitemap=https://yourdomain.x0/sitemap.xml
[replace uri with your http complete url/to/sitemap.xml file]
Google official docs : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183669